# Using GWT JSNI to integrate with js files

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

I am currently working on a GWT project and it now needs to used by an external JavaScript file. I am creating a test prototype right now to ensure both sides are working properly.

When I run and compile, I see the console logs in the browser from the events being called. However, the GWT java methods are not being called.

After trying many scenarios, I also noticed that if I remove the `$entry` wrapper from the `exportStaticMethods()`, the opposite occurs. I see the `System.out`s being called in my java code, however the console logs from the JavaScript in the browser are not being called.

I am trying to figure what is causing the behavior and if there is a small missing piece I overlooked.

I have already reviewed the GWT JSNI documentation for [calling a Java method from js](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling) and tried to find a solution from other related questions on StackOverflow.

**GWT and Java side**

I have gone into the `onModuleLoad()` method of my `EntryPoint` class and added a static method called `exportStaticMethods()`. I also created the `PokePingClass.java` file listed below.

EntryPointClass.java

```
public class EntryPointClass implements EntryPoint {

    @Override public void onModuleLoad() {
        exportStaticMethods();
        // load application here.
    }

    public static native void exportStaticMethods() /*-{

        $wnd.pingApp = $entry((function) {
                           @com.application.PokePingClass::pingApp()();
                       });

        $wnd.pokeApp = $entry((function) {
                           @com.application.PokePingClass::pokeApp()();
                       });
    }-*/
}
```

PokePingClass.java

```
public class PokePingClass {

    public static void pokeApp() {
        System.out.println("pokeApp() called");
    }

    public static void pingApp() {
        System.out.println("pingApp() called");
    }
}
```

**HTML and js**

In the `.html` file of the project, I added a hidden `div` element of id 'pokePing', as well as the `pokeping.js` file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        .
        . <!-- other stuff -->
        .
        <script type='text/javascript' src='pokeping.js</script> 
    </head>

    <body>
        .
        . <!-- other stuff -->
        .
        <div id="pokePing" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

pokeping.js

```
$(document).ready(function) {

    var $pp = $('#pokePing');

    var pokeApp = function() {
        console.log("app handling poke event");
        window.parent.pokeApp();
    }

    var pingApp = function() {
        console.log("app handling ping event");
        window.parent.pingApp();
    }

    $pp.trigger('pokeApp');
    $pp.trigger('pingApp');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar post but the key was to actually return the method calls in the JSNI functions. After that, all works well.

```
public static native void exportStaticMethods() /*-{

    $wnd.pingApp = $entry((function) {
                       return @com.application.PokePingClass::pingApp()();
                   });

    $wnd.pokeApp = $entry((function) {
                       return @com.application.PokePingClass::pokeApp()();
                   });
}-*/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static native void exportStaticMethods() /*-{

    $wnd.pingApp = $entry(function) {
                       @com.application.PokePingClass.pingApp()();
                   }

    $wnd.pokeApp = $entry(function) {
                       @com.application.PokePingClass.pokeApp()();
                   }
}-*/
```

This isn't valid JS, and doesn't make sense as JSNI. Try this instead:

```
    $wnd.pingApp = $entry(function() {
                       @com.application.PokePingClass::pingApp()();
                   });

    $wnd.pokeApp = $entry(function() {
                       @com.application.PokePingClass::pokeApp()();
                   });
```

Edit because I still had it wrong, forgot the `::` operator for members.

Comment: Apologies. I corrected the JSNI syntax for the functions. I am still observing the same issues. I forgot to note that I am using jquery-2.2.4.min.js as well. It is currently not running in no conflicts mode if that helps. This question is also cross referenced in the SmartGWT forums as I am using that framework as well.

Comment: Aside from the methods not being called, there are no other errors in your browser's console? Are you certain that System.out does what you think it does in a browser?

Comment: Sorry late response. I found a similar answer on SO. I can't find the OP but will provide the link when I come across it. For some reason when I add a return to the JSNI functions, it seems to work and I see the System.out statements.